# How do I write a YAML file using a dictionary with long keys and values?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a Python dictionary that has 25-30 key-value pairs. The keys are fairly long strings (20-30 characters), and the values can be 1-10 lines long with embedded new-lines, etc.

I would like to write this to a file using YAML, but if I use `yaml.dump` it is not very readable, because of the length of the data. I would really like the file to look like the following example:

```
This_is_my_very_long_key_1    : "This is some value for key 1"
This_is_a_shorter_key         : "This is the value
                                for that key"
```

I am finding the YAML documentation fairly sparse.

I tried using `default_flow_style=False` or `True`, and it looked better with `no-flow`, but that's not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the width of the line by passing the `width` parameter to the dump method.

```
yaml.dump(d,  width=20, default_flow_style=False)
```